# RxJS throwError's error not show in the subscribe's error handler

Tags: angular, rxjs

Here is my code:

```js
import { interval, throwError } from "rxjs";
import { take, map } from "rxjs/operators";

interval(1000)
  .pipe(
    take(5),
    map(x => {
      if (x > 0) {
        // throw new Error("error");
        return throwError(x);
      }
      return x;
    })
  )
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log("data------>", data);
    },
    error => {
      console.log("error------>", error);
    }
  );
```

I try to use `throwError` to return error at the very begin of the stream, but all of them drop into the subscribe success handler, according to the console log, the error are all observables.

However, I expect the errors fall into the error handler. I think I must misunderstood how the `throwError` work. What I missed? How can I fix this? And I found out only if I throw real `new Error`, the error can fall into the error handler

Here is the demo: [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/rxjs-playground-kuz4c)

Comment: map transforms a value into a different value. So, you've transformed a number into an Observable. You thus created an Observable<number | Observable>. You want switchMap(), not map().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`throwError`**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/throw.html) would return an `Observable` and `map`ping would simply make the original value wrapped in two `Observable`s.

Try returning an `Observable` wrapping the number instead of simply returning a `number` outside `if`. You can use [**`of`**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/of.html) to do it.

And then use [**`switchMap`**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) instead of [**`map`**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html)

Something like this:

```
import { interval, throwError } from "rxjs";
import { of } from "rxjs";
import { take, switchMap } from "rxjs/operators";

interval(1000)
  .pipe(
    take(5),
    switchMap(x => {
      if (x > 0) {
        // throw new Error("error");
        return throwError(x);
      }
      return of(x);
    })
  )
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log("data------>", data);
    },
    error => {
      console.log("error------>", error);
    }
  );
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample Demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/rxjs-playground-m3qgq) for your ref.